# Module not found Error while deploying website

Tags: python, django, deployment

I am tyring to deploy a django project on pythonanywhere.com, The project runs fine on the local server.

I'm using a free account, I have created a virtual env and I've installed all required modules including django. I have also edited the wsgi.py file as follows:

```
path = '/home/karmah24/reporting_portal'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'portal.settings'
```

I'm getting a "Module not found Error: test.urls not found" even though I've added this to the main project urls, and this project works on my local server.

https://github.com/Karmah24/reporting_portal is my github repository that I want to deploy.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is from your settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

your app for test folder is missing in INSTALLED_APPS

Also, in your test/apps.py

You have used app name as `calc`

Comment: I changed the app name, and in the installed apps list I added 'test'. Now the debug page isn't showing up instead the pythonanwhere something went wrong page comes up.

Comment: Can you please try to deploy this through your account please?

Comment: If you're getting the "Something went wrong" page, there will be tracebacks in your error log that you can use to start debugging.

Comment: @ArunT Nope, I made the edits you pointed out, got the "something wrong page", tried changing the paths and got back to the module not found error(test.urls). I would really appreciate if you could try deploying through your account if it wont take much time